# R: dealing with NON-unique row names when assigning column elements to be row names in an existing data frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to reassigning the 1st column of my dataset into row names/titles and leave the rest of the dataframe to be treated as variables. I have seen the reassigning codes:

```
samp2 <- samp[,-1]
rownames(samp2) <- samp[,1]
```

The problem. however, is the elements in my first column are names, so they have duplicates since the same person could be measured multiple times.

```
> samp 
      names Var.1 Var.2 Var.3
 1     A     1     5     0
 2     B     2     4     1
 3     C     3     3     2
 4     A     4     2     3
 5     B     5     1     4
 ...
```

This gives me an error of "non-unique names". I do not want to combine/merge the rows. How I achieve my goal to make my dataframe into :

```
> samp.with.rownames 
     Var.1 Var.2 Var.3
A     1     5     0
B     2     4     1
C     3     3     2
A     4     2     3
B     5     1     4
...
```

Comment: You cannot have duplicate row names in R, at least not with dataframes. You can turn your `samp` into a matrix though and there it'll be possible.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to do this. Every row in a dataframe is a unique observation so it has a unique row name. If you want to be able to subset the data frame , it is easier to do this by leaving the columns as they are and grouping by them when needed. It's easy to get by in R without ever using row names in a data frame

Comment: @arg0naut91 yes I think you are right. I might have to matrix it.

Comment: @AllanCameron haha, you are right. Yes, I actually first did subset on the dataset to perform scale it and did some analysis. Then I want to a PCA, and it is that moment I realised I do need to include the 1st column's ID (text) back into my plot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned already in comments that you cannot have duplicate row names in dataframe but if you need it, you can have them in a matrix.

```
mat <- matrix(unlist(samp[-1]), ncol = ncol(samp) - 1,
              dimnames = list(samp$names, names(samp[-1])))
mat

#  Var.1 Var.2 Var.3
#A     1     5     0
#B     2     4     1
#C     3     3     2
#A     4     2     3
#B     5     1     4
```

Here we use -1 to remove the first column from the dataframe.

**data**

```
samp <- structure(list(names = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B"), Var.1 = 1:5, 
Var.2 = 5:1, Var.3 = 0:4), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```